# VBA - Extract last word from string and create new string from extraction

Tags: vba, excel

I have this function for selecting customer

```
Function GetFolder() As String 
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With fldr
        .Title = "Select"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Canceled")
            Exit Function
        Else:
            sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
            GoTo NextCode
        End If
    End With

NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

User selected BMW folder or Toyota
so `sItem = "T:\DOCUMENTATION\BMW"`
or `sItem = "T:\DOCUMENTATION\TOYOTA"`

I need extract from string (`sItem`) which customer was selected (`BMW`, `Toyota`) and create a new extraction string `sItemCustomer`

so result will be `sItemCustomer = "BMW"`

Could you help me to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SPLIT` is what you need, or a little more work, `INSTR` or `INSTRREV` and `MID` or `RIGHT`

`split(sItem,"\")(2)`

To do "properly",

```
Function pop(strInput As String, Optional strDelim As String = "\") As String
    Dim a() As String
    a = Split(strInput, strDelim)
    pop = a(UBound(a))
    Erase a
End Function
```

Comment: To be compatible to both Windows *and* OSX Office versions you can use `Application.PathSeparator` instead of `\ ` as parameter for `strDelim`.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I don't understand how should I connect this function with my string `sItem` and how can I get extraction string from that

Comment: `strInput` `lastword=pop(strInput)`

Answer (score 2):

As *Nathan_Sav* stated above, another approach would be:

```
sItemCustomer = Right(sItem, Len(sItem) - InStrRev(sItem, "\"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a UDF to extract nth word from a string. Just replace the space with your character in the line 20,21,22
Also formula to find the last word without effort would be - =ExtractWord(B2,LEN(B2)-LEN((SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",""))))
or

### =ExtractWord("STring",number of word)

```
Function ExtractWord(r As Range, WordCoice As Integer)
Dim CompanyName As String 
CompanyName = Trim(r.Value) 
CompanyNameLen = Len(CompanyName) 
CompanyNameWordCount = Len(Trim(CompanyName)) - Len(Replace(Trim(CompanyName), " ", "")) + 1 
If CompanyNameWordCount > 1 Then 
    Choice = WordCoice 
Else 
    ExtractWord = CompanyName 
    Exit Function 
End If 
If Choice > CompanyNameWordCount Or Choice < 1 Then 
    ExtractWord = "#N/A" 
    Exit Function 
Else
WordPos = 1
Count = 1
Do While Count <= Choice
Count = Count + 1
    If InStr(1, CompanyName, " ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ChosenWord = Mid(CompanyName, 1, InStr(1, CompanyName, " ", vbTextCompare) - 1)
        WordPos = InStr(1, CompanyName, " ", vbTextCompare) + 1 
        CompanyName = Mid(CompanyName, WordPos, CompanyNameLen) 
    Else
        ChosenWord = CompanyName
    End If 
Loop
ExtractWord = ChosenWord
End If
End Function
```